# Django Test mock instance of module variable

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test my Django app which has a proxy API which is instantiated in its own module.

**api.py**

```
class ProxyApi(object):
   def __init__(self, server_info):
       pass

   def validate_login(self, credentials):
       # call to real api here

api = ProxyAPi()
```

**middlewares.py**

```
from mymodule.api import api

class MyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if api.validate_login():
            # do something with proxy api
```

**views.py**

```
from mymodule.api import api

class TaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    def get(self, request):
        if api.validate_login():
            # do something with proxy api
```

**tests.py**

```
class InputTasksViewTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mymodule.api.ProxyAPi')
    def test_add(self, mock_api):
        mock_api.validate_login.return_value = True
        response = self.client.get(reverse('task'))
```

The original `validate_login`is still called.

I would like to know how to handle the instantiation of ProxyApi while still retaining mocking capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my own solution, the problem was that once Django started, it read some files (like models or views or middlewares) that automatically instantiated api variable from import.

I just needed to defer this instantiation so I can mock the ProxyApi object, here's what I did:

```
api = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: ProxApi())
```

Answer (score -3):

You have `def validate_login(self, credentials):` in api
and in middleware you define below code. So How you will send creadentials to API from middleware `api.validate_login(<You should send credentials to api as parameter>):`

```
from mymodule.api import api

class MyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if api.validate_login():
            pass
```

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand your answer, this question is about mocking, my middleware and my view are fine, I just need heed with mocking my ProxyApi object